# parry3d - self collision of a shape?

Tags: rust, collision-detection

Reading [Parry3d documentation](https://docs.rs/parry3d/latest/parry3d/index.html), I understand that we can know when two shapes will collide and many different things.

But how to test for self-collision for a deformable sphere (or any other shape, really, cube, plane) ? Right now, it seems that two different shapes must be engaged.

#### Application

A sphere takes a hit and this deformed portion gets back hitting the non hit side, it should not go through.

#### Question

So, is there a function I missed in the doc that helps achieving this ?

Thanks

Comment: actually, I will measure the neighbours distance at steps and predict if it will collide or not. But if there is something "automatic" do not hesitate